# How to use PIP with Python 3.8 in Fedora 31?

Tags: pip, fedora, python-3.8

I tried to use PIP to install some package, but it seems the `pip` module is missing:

```sh
$ python3.8 -m pip install bpython
/usr/bin/python3.8: No module named pip
```

Is it even included in the `python38` package?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfedora%5D+%5Bpip%5D+install+pip

Comment: Replace `3.6` with `3.8` in the accepted answer.